# Create mmap within virtual ramdisk

Tags: c, linux, ramdisk

How can I use mmap to reserve memory within a virtual ramdisk? Lets say I do:

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=10m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

I now have a virtual ramdisk, but how do I map to it within my C program?

```
int main() {
    // ....
    addr = mmap(/* ramdisk address? */, size, PROT_READ_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
```

Comment: If you're using a RAMdisk then using `mmap` would just invoke overhead. Why not use `fopen`?

Comment: @Dai I'm using mmap as a way of reserving a region of memory for my library, but I am not sure how I would go about doing such a thing if I want to reserve this memory within a ramdisk instead of providing mmap the value of `NULL` for an address hint

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `/mnt/ramdisk` is a tmpfs doesn't have any bearing on how you use it.

If you wanted to memory-map a file on that device, you'd `open()` a file and map it with `MAP_FILE` (not `MAP_ANONYMOUS`) just as if it were a normal file. Don't pass an address; an appropriate one will be chosen for you.

Comment: But can I use that ramdisk for direct memory access? I can't simply call open() on a directory like `/mnt/ramdisk`

Comment: No. The semantics don't change just because it's a tmpfs -- it behaves exactly like any other filesystem.